# User variable in where clause for 'IN'

Tags: mysql, where-clause, user-variables

I'm getting a problem using user-variables in MYSQL. Here's the code I've written. This isn't producing any errors but is not showing the desired results.

```
set @org_id_list := (select c.id from tbl_companyinformations c
left join tbl_users u on c.user_id = u.id
where u.email_address LIKE '%pdatar%'
);
select * from tbl_c2c_offers where 
seller_org_id IN (@org_id_list) or buyer_org_id IN (@org_id_list)
```

But then when I run this in MySQL, it doesn't return the required rows. If I copy the select statement used to define the user variable in the where statement of the second select statement, the required results are shown. What I mean is, the following code produces the required results.

```
select * from tbl_c2c_offers where 
seller_org_id IN (select c.id from tbl_companyinformations c
    left join tbl_users u on c.user_id = u.id
    where u.email_address LIKE '%pdatar%'
) or 
buyer_org_id IN (select c.id from tbl_companyinformations c
    left join tbl_users u on c.user_id = u.id
    where u.email_address LIKE '%pdatar%'
);
```

What am I doing wrong the first time around? As I said, the statements don't cause any errors, but the required results are not shown.

Thanks in advance for your time in helping me.

Cheers,

Prathamesh

Comment: Use the second version.  In the first version, you seem to be trying to store a list of values in a variable and then using them using `in`.  You can't really get that to work, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I am using the second version right now but that just seems so inefficient, because I'm having to do a select statement twice which is returning the same values. I'll have to read in Dynamic SQL then.

Comment: If so, store the results in a temporary table, not a string.